# Equally split navbar with centered image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to achieve a `navbar` that is equally divided into 12 columns so that each `li` takes up one section each. I would like to have an image in my starting column. This is what I have so far:

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%; /*Fixes the height to 100% of the viewport*/
}
body {
  padding-top: 65px; /*50px for the height of the navbar + 37px for the offset*/
}

.navbar-inverse {
  background-color: #06658D;
  border: 0;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a {
  color: #FFF;
  width: 100px;
  line-height: 25px;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > img {
  max-height: 25px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Dashboard</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/layout.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container row">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav ">
                    <li class="col-md-1"><img src="images/Home.png" alt="home"></li>
                    <li class="col-md-1"><a href="#">Column 2</a></li>
                    <li class="col-md-1"><a href="#">Column 3</a></li>
                    <li class="col-md-1"><a href="#">Column 4</a></li>
                    <li class="col-md-1"><a href="#">Column 5</a></li>
                    <li class="col-md-1"><a href="#">Column 6</a></li>

                    <li class="col-md-1"><a href="#">Column 7</a></li>
                    <li class="col-md-1"><a href="#">Column 8</a></li>
                    <li class="col-md-1"><a href="#">Column 9</a></li>
                    <li class="col-md-1"><a href="#">Column 10</a></li>
                    <li class="col-md-1"><a href="#">Column 11</a></li>
                    <li class="col-md-1"><a href="#">Column 12</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="container body-content row">
        @RenderBody()  
    </div>
    @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

These two combined however result in this:

[image]

AS you can see I have two issues. Firstly the alignment of the image is all wrong as I would like that to be central both horizontally and vertically. Secondly my `navbar` is not divided up into 12 equal elements as they are not utilizing the full width of the `navbar`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using display table property. I don't think you're gonna get equal li sizes but you'll get a result none the less.

```
ul {
   display: table;
   width: 100%;
}
ul li {
   display: table-cell;
   text-align: center;
}
```